# GeoPandas ParseException: Invalid HEX char error

Tags: python, postgis, geopandas, well-known-binary

I am trying to read a geospatial table from a PostGIS database on PostgreSQL. 
Using the funcion

```
sql = '''SELECT ST_AsText(geom) AS geom  FROM my_table;'''
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, con, geom_col='geom' )
```

I got back this error

```
ParseException: Invalid HEX char
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nuts3_grid_intersection.py", line 35, in <module>
    df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, con, geom_col='geom' )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 274, in from_postgis
    index_col=index_col, coerce_float=coerce_float, params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/geopandas/io/sql.py", line 55, in read_postgis
    geoms = df[geom_col].apply(load_geom)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 3194, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1472, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/geopandas/io/sql.py", line 54, in load_geom
    return shapely.wkb.loads(str(x), hex=hex_encoded)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/shapely/wkb.py", line 14, in loads
    return reader.read_hex(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 409, in read_hex
    "Could not create geometry because of errors "
shapely.errors.WKBReadingError: Could not create geometry because of errors while reading input.
```

I am not able to find a solution for it. 
I have geom data on a `WKB` format. I had the same issue also if I convert them using the functions `ST_AsBinary(geom)` and  `ST_GeomFromWKB("geom",SRID)`.

I run the PostgiGIS code:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromWKB(decode('geom ', 'hex'), 4258) FROM my_table;
```

I got that output

```
ERROR:  invalid hexadecimal digit: "g"
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid hexadecimal digit: "g"
SQL state: 22023
```

How can postgis read the geometry data even if the HEx standard on the WKB is not correct?

How could I solve this?

Comment: you are passing in `'geom'`, i.e. the column name as a **string**! use with `ST_GeomFromWKB(geom, 4326)` (no `""`) to get the geometry in PostGIS' universal hex format. (to make that clear: `decode('geom', 'hex')` will try to decode the string `'geom'`, and not the text representation of the geom column values)

Comment: yes, that's was because I created that table with pandas and I didn't realize that I had values on the table without geometries. When I wanted to make a geo-spatial operation, geopandas tolde me It was not able to read the geometries correctly (because some or them were None!!) I deleted it from the table and I had no issue...

Comment: Have you solved your issue? :)

Comment: @kogexo, yes. The issues was create a geospatial postgis table using pandas and not geopandas. I had no issue to visualize the data on QGIS but I did have problems when I tried to used geopandas. I solved the issue create the postgis table using geopandas :)

Comment: @GloriP. Nice, glad to read that! My problem was that geometries were multiparts and not singleparts. Thanks for your answer.